# Testing if a number has a decimal value without any library

Tags: c++

I need to test if a number has a decimal value in C++. I only want to use `<iostream>` and no other library, but I'm curious if the method I'm using would be acceptable. If you can offer any assistance finding a better way that would be great.

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    double x, y;
    std::cin >> x;
    int z = x;
    if (x - z != 0) {
        std::cout << "It's a decimal.";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "It's not a decimal.";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Upon thinking about this longer, I came up with a new function that seems more acceptable.

```
double TestForDecimal(double Num) {
    double z;
    while (Num > 1) {
        if (Num > 101) /* Increments down to 1 more quickly */ {
        Num = Num - 100;
    }
        else if (Num > 12) { Num = Num - 10; }
        else { Num--; }
    }
    if (Num < 1 && Num > 0) {
        std::cout << "This number has a decimal value" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Theres no decimal" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's a "decimal value"?

Comment: Although casting to `int` doesn't work across the entire range of `double`, it does work, better, everywhere your new function does.  You may want to consider `if (Num > -INT_MAX && Num < INT_MAX && Num == (int)Num)`, in order to avoid undefined behavior.

Comment: I don't understand your second appoarch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two "correct" ways to test:

- Isolate the fraction with `std::fmod(x, 1.0)`.
- Discard the fraction using `floor` or `ceil` or `trunc`, e.g. test whether `x == std::floor(x)`.

And one incorrect way:

- Casting to an integral type will fail (with undefined behavior!) for numbers outside the range of the destination type, so this is not suitable for validation of untrusted input (and if the input is trusted, why does it need to be validated?)

> A prvalue of a ﬂoating point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type.  The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded.  **The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type.**

Comment: Yet another option is [`std::modf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/modf) to extract the non-integral component.

Comment: Although your code shows me the correct ways to test for a decimal, I couldn't use it because fmod, floor, ciel, or trunc are outside of the iostream library. I have answered my own question after I thought longer on it, and I feel your help made it possible. If its possible, could you check out the new function I made for it and give me your criticism. Thanks!

Comment: @Jacobardio: iostream hasn't been a separate library since before C++98 (and back then, the header was `<iostream.h>`).  All of this is part of the C++ Standard Library.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  double a;
  std::cin >> a;
  if(int(a) != a)
  {
      std::cout << "decimal";
  }
  else
  {
      std::cout << "no decimal";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This probably has the desired behavior on the expected range of input, but it has the potential to fail miserably.  Better to use `std::fmod(x, 1.0)`

Comment: But what actually fmod(num,1.0) does?